# Assigning a pointer to the const function arguement pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Say I have a const pointer to an array as a function argument like so:

```
int* test(const int* inputArg)
```

And within the function I want to assign inputArg as one of the members of a struct, like so:

```
typedef struct {
    int * intArray;
} structSample;

structSample abc;
abc.intArray = inputArg;
```

How should I cast inputArg to achieve this? Right now if I compile it, error will be shown saying that

```
error: assigning to 'int *' from 'const int *'
```

Thank you

Comment: If the function (potentially) modifies the object pointed to, then don't lie to the user, and change the function definition.

Comment: This may be [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). How to cast is obvious: `abc.intArray = (int*)inputArg;`, but you shouldn't do this because what is pointed at by `inputArg` is const but what is pointed by `intArray` isn't, so it means the data may be modified.

Comment: The best solutions are to either change the structure member to be `int const *intArray`, or change the function argument to be `int *inputArg`.  If you really want to circumvent the type system and force the compiler to accept it, you can use `abc.intArray = (int *) inputArg;` as a last resort.

Comment: May know what was the purpose of `const int* inputArg` inside the function then?

Comment: @TomKarzes I have tried the method of making struct member as "intArray", but somehow the values inside are then no longer the same as inputArg.

Comment: @sjsam This is actually for a homework exercise, which the function arguments are given as "const int* inputArg". What I need to achieve is make a struct with its member as inputArg, without the use of a for loop.

Comment: @Boku . I see. Time to change teacher pal ! ;)

Comment: @sjsam hehe I wished I could ;)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you do not have

> a const pointer to an array

What you have is a pointer to constant integer. If you really wanted a constant pointer to integer as an argument, you would have to have the prototype declared as follows:

```
int* test(int* const inputArg)
```

Unless, of course, something else was in mind.

---

*Update from comment:*

So basically if you want to have a pointer to constant int stored in your function as a struct member, you can declare it just like that:

```
struct SampleStruct
{
  const int* a;
  /* whatever follows */
};

int* test(const int* inputArg)
{
  struct SampleStruct ss;
  ss.a = inputArg;
  /* other code */
}
```

You must be aware, that in doing so, you must be const correct. That means, since both (argument and field) are pointers to constant integers, you must not change the values at that address(es).

Comment: Yeah I meant a pointer to constant integer, sorry. What is shown in the question is what is intended. My aim is to make a struct with its member as "inputArg", without using a for loop to make a copy of "inputArg". I have tried making the struct member defition as "int const *intArray", but some how the values no longer match inputArg when I do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
abc.intArray = (int*)inputArg;
```

This is the `C-style cast`. On a side not the compiler didn't allow the const conversion by default because it's dangerous to do so. You are removing the const at your own risk.
For eg if your `test` is called like

```
const int max = 100;
//centuries later
test(&max);
```

and you do go ahead with the cast:

```
abc.intArray = (int*)inputArg;
// after another century later
*(abc.intArray) = 10; // kaboom. Undefined behavior. Debugging is a nightmare at this point
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here would be changing the function to

```
int* test(int* inputArg)
{
/* do whatever you wish to do with inputArg itself
 * why  bother to create a structure and all?
 * The whole purpose you wanted the const int* inputArg
 * was to prevent any accidental change of data pointed to by it
 * Wasn't it?
 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you are using `Werror` flag (this shouldn't be an error but a warning)

There is a way to lie to the compiler (using unions) without warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *test(const int *inputArg)
{
    union {int *nonconstant; const int *constant;} fake = {.constant = inputArg};
    int *p = fake.nonconstant;

    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int x = 500;
    int *p = test(&x);

    *p = 100; /* Boom */
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by others, don't do it :)

Comment: This is clearly not what the op wishes to do. But nice technique anyway

Comment: @sjsam: Then I don't understand the question, can you clarify what is OP trying to do?

Comment: I meant the op didn't wanted it this sophisticated ;)  He was just asking how to cast a (const int*) to (int*)

Comment: Ah, ok, I agree!, that's why I said don't do it :)